# Looking for a .NET Math Equation Editor and Solver Control

Tags: c#, math, latex, equation, solver

I am looking for a 3rd party custom control that can handle both editing and solving simple math equations (with image generation).

I know about LaTeX and using its syntax to generate images of math equations (i've used this project here that implements LaTeX: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Eq2Img.aspx), and i have found several projects that can take an equation as an inputted string, compile, parse, and solve the equation (here is one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/EvaluationEngine.aspx).

However, i have yet to find anything that will allow you to both build an equation with an outputted preview image (like LaTeX does), and then allow you specify values for the variables in the equation, and solve the equation with the result outputted.

Does anyone know if any 3rd party control exists that can do both editing and solving of math equations? I am using C# .NET 4.0 so hopefully i can use the library/control in .NET.

Any help or links to something similar would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3):

You can use special .NET control - [Math Expression Editor Light](http://othercontrols.com/en/products/mathexpressioneditorlight/). It is symbolic math expr editor + computing enviroment.

see [img](http://s14.radikal.ru/i187/1104/3a/fd7df1461f85.jpg)

Comment: Hi, Andrey. I removed the spam flags from your answers as they seem to be solidly on-topic. However, you should be aware that users that come to StackOverflow and just post links to a single product page often get deleted, because the perception is that they are just here to promote their website or blog, and not contribute. Keep this in mind when posting future answers. Also, if you are affiliated with this product, you need to disclose that. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787

Comment: By now, we have many great free solutions. Just search for "Tex" in the NuGet package manager for options. One example: https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math

Answer (score 0):

Solving math equations isn't really as straightforward as it seems, so you are not going to find a control that can both edit AND solve equations.  Some 'equations' can't even be solved by a computer in the first place.  It seems to me that you have already located two resources that are working for you, in a broad sense so you'd probably be better off just combining them yourself as you will spend more time looking for one that already exists.

Comment: yes, i know its not easy, if it were, i'd do it myself...but that's why i am looking for a 3rd party custom control that could do this...if you have ever seen microsoft mathematics i am looking for something just like that...where you can enter in an equation and it formats it properly, and then solves it. I don't really need anything too extensive just basic algebra equations would do...like (2x + 3y) / (10z) = A, then be able to plug in actual values for x, y, and z, to solve for A....theres gotta be something out there...

Comment: Most custom controls and components that you see out there are for more general purposes.  Your purposes are VERY specific and that is why you are not going to find something like this.  I mean, have you noticed that there are lots of 3rd party components for either part of your needs (solving and display) but not one for both?